# Mongo Dynamic Search Keys And Value Query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nodes

How can query in Mongo DB , by the way I am using Keystone JS. I wanted to filter or get result from the Vehicle Model where keys and values from for example  { 'Year' => '2019,2018', 'Make' => 'Acura,BMW' } . It will filter where year = 2019 , 2018 same with the Make.

## My current code

```
view.on('init', function (next) {

        var q = keystone.list('Vehicle').paginate({
            page: req.query.page || 1,
            perPage: 10,
            maxPages: 10,
            filters: {
                state: 'published',

            },
        })

            .sort('-publishedDate')

        if (locals.filters.searchkeys) {

            let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(locals.filters.searchkeys)


            for (var key of urlSearchParams.keys()) {

                console.log("The Key :" , key)

                //this part is where it would be dynamic
                q.where('Year').in();


            }

        }
```

## Search Param

```
{ 'Year' => '2019,2018', 'Make' => 'Acura,BMW' }
```

## Collection

```
{ total: 12,
  results:
   [ { _id: 5d6893cdc02d0e3020f84c85,
       DriveType: 'FWD',
       FuelType: 'Gasoline Fuel',
       ImageList:
        '',
       Options:
        'Traction Control,Stability Control,Front Wheel Drive,Tires - Front All-Season,Tires - Rear All-Season,Aluminum Wheels,Power Steering,4-Wheel Disc Brakes,ABS,Brake Assist,Sun/Moonroof,Generic 
Sun/Moonroof,Rear Spoiler,Automatic Headlights,Fog Lamps,Heated Mirrors,Power Mirror(s),Privacy Glass,Intermittent Wipers,Variable Speed Intermittent Wipers,Leather Seats,Power Driver Seat,Bucket Seats,Heated Front Seat(s),Driver Adjustable Lumbar,Passenger Adjustable Lumbar,3rd Row Seat,Pass-Through Rear Seat,Floor Mats,Steering Wheel Audio Controls,Adjustable Steering Wheel,Engine Immobilizer,Tire Pressure Monitor,Power Windows,Power Door Locks,Universal Garage Door Opener,Keyless Entry,Cruise Control,Security System,Climate Control,A/C,Rear A/C,Rear Defrost,AM/FM Stereo,CD Changer,CD Player,Satellite Radio,Entertainment System,Power Outlet,Driver Vanity Mirror,Passenger Vanity Mirror,Driver Illuminated Vanity Mirror,Passenger Illuminated Visor Mirror,Rear Reading Lamps,Driver Air Bag,Passenger Air Bag,Front Side Air Bag,Passenger Air Bag Sensor,Front Head Air Bag,Rear Head Air Bag,Child Safety Locks',
       Description: '',
       DateInStock: '7/15/2019',
       Invoice: 3000,
       BookValue: '3686',
       MSRP: 0,
       SellingPrice: 5592,
       Miles: 162111,
       Transmission: 'Automatic',
       EngineDisplacement: '3.5L',
       EngineCylinders: '6',
       InteriorColor: '',
       ExteriorColor: 'Gray',
       Doors: 4,
       ModelNumber: 'YF2867JNW',
       Trim: 'Ex-L',
       Body: 'Convertible',
       Model: 'Pilot',
       Make: 'Honda',
       Year: 2007,
       VIN: '5FNYF28677B037628',
       Stock: 'K2501A',
       Type: 'Used',
       image_gallery: [],
       __v: 0,
       CategorizedOptions: '',
       Comment: '',
       name: '',
       publishedDate: null,
       content: [Object],
       categories: [],
       image: [Object],
       state: 'published',
       Certified: true } ],
  currentPage: 1,
  totalPages: 2,
  pages: [ 1, 2 ],
  previous: false,
  next: 2,
  first: 1,
  last: 1 }
```

Comment: Can you please add input collection sample

Comment: you mean the data ?

Comment: Yes, the collection's (vehicle collection) sample json data on which you're querying.

Comment: okay wait ill put it

Comment: @sushantmehta i have added the collection

Comment: I have just provide 1 object , i think thats enough

Comment: @sushantmehta are you still there ?

Comment: in keystone can you use $in and other mongo expressions in find()?

Comment: yes you can use $in and other mongo expressions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198927/discussion-between-mr-rajiv-kumar-and-sushant-mehta).

Comment: you have any questions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say query is request params coming to backend as

```
let request={'Year':'2019,2018', 'Make':'Acura,BMW'}

let query={}
if(request.Year){
  let year=request.Year.split(',')         // will give array ['2019','2018']

  for(let i=0;i<year.length;i++){          //for making array of nos [2019,2018]
   year[i]=parseInt(year[i]) 
  }

  query.Year={$in:year}                       // {$in:['2019','2018']}
}
if(request.Make){
  query.Make={$in:request.Make.split(',')}     // {$in:['Acura','BMW']}
}

var Vehicle = keystone.list('Vehicle');

let q= Vehicle.model.find(query)
  .where('state', 'published')
  .populate('author')
  .sort('-publishedAt')
  .limit(5)
  .exec(function(err, posts) {
    // do something with posts
  });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198984/discussion-on-answer-by-sushant-mehta-mongo-dynamic-search-keys-and-value-query).

Comment: best choice would be server side pagination i think sir